# Getting an error "Unable to load the requested class: oauth2"

Tags: php, codeigniter, oauth-2.0

I have a fresh version of CI running and I've installed the [codeigniter-oauth2](http://getsparks.org/packages/oauth2/versions/HEAD/show) spark via bash on my Ubuntu instances on EC2.

I followed the directions of the documentation and created a controller called auth using the demo code.

I have looked in my sparks folder and all the correct files/folders are there (as well as the /0.4.0 folder).

I have added the Facebook

My autoloads file has this

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session','OAuth2');
```

Now when I open the page mydomain.com/auth/sessions/facebook I get the error

"Unable to load the requested class: oauth2"

I can't seem to find any other assistance online regarding this issue online. I don't think it's an issue of not having the right case as I have tried all different ways of writing it.

Any direction to fix this issues would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you find what is problem with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use lower case when loading libraries.

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session','oauth2');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$autoload['sparks'] = array('OAuth2/0.4.0');
```